# magento 2.4.2 updated get The store will not work correctly in the case when cookies are disabled

Tags: cookie, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.2

When I upgraded my webiste from M2.3.5 to M2.4.2, I get this notice "The store will not work correctly in the case when cookies are disabled." on top of head frontend for 3 seconds. But I installed a new M2.4.2 have not get that notice(Cookie Restriction Mode = No) . I found div id named "cookie status" The store will not work correctly in the case when cookies are disabled. but I can't find which file can control this. I don't need the notice display, so how to do that? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of how to hide this notice with CSS as it is causing CLS in some situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's taking time to hide because there is using js for hide. you can
> use css for hide instaed  of $script =
> 'document.querySelector("#cookie-status").style.display = "none";';
>
> Content comes from
> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/cookie_status.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>

<div id="cookie-status">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('The store will not work correctly in the case when cookies are disabled.')); ?>
</div>
<?php
$script = 'document.querySelector("#cookie-status").style.display = "none";';
?>
<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', ['type' => 'text/javascript'], $script, false); ?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "cookieStatus": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Link to the official commit on 2.4-develop : https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/309e020aa7de1bd4e2af30519cff879ddbed5a74

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the missing code in Magento_Theme::js/cookie_status.phtml

```
<?php
   $script = 'document.querySelector("#cookie-status").style.display = "none";';
?>
<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', ['type' => 'text/javascript'], $script, false); ?>
```

We chose not to add this code as it causes delay and potentially Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS). Our solution is to use CSS to hide the element:

```
#cookie-status {
    display: none;
}
```

You can also remove the block entirely from the head by adding the following to

app/code//Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <referenceBlock name="cookie-status-check" remove="true"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

This solution may present a problem when the element's data is required if the user has not enabled cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2.4.3

Solution:- Use this CSS to hide the element in your theme frontend folder
Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

.cookie-status-message {
display: none;
}